# QTPro.exe is missing

Tags: qtp, hp-uft

I have uninstalled UFT11.53 and installed QTP11.0 successfully, but after successful installation also I couldn't access/launch the QTP.

Because QTPro.exe is missing, even I have verified the same in C:\ drive, it's not there.

> "C:\Program Files (x86)\HP\QuickTest Professional\bin\QTPro.exe" - is
>   missing

I already had QTP11.0, then upgraded to UFT11.53. Now, I'm again going back to QTP11.0 because of my project requirements.

And please also be informed that I have uninstalled all the HP UFT specific items from 'Control Panel', and then only started the installation and done it successfully. But still I'm facing this, please help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

That's an interesting use of the phrase *successful installation* :)

If possible I would recommend re-imaging the machine, I usually use virtual machines for UFT/QTP.

Otherwise I would un-install QTP and then clean up your machine.

**Note: This is a bit risky, it's best to backup files and the registry. I take no responsibility for any problems that may occur if you follow this advice.**

First deleting the following directories

- `C:\Program Files (x86)\HP\QuickTest Professional`
- `C:\Program Files (x86)\HP\Unified Functional Testing`

And in the registry, delete

- `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Mercury Interactive\QuickTest Professional`
- `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Mercury Interactive\QuickTest Professional`

After that, hopefully, you will be able to install QTP in a really successful manner.